# If I have X11 forwarding turned on. How do I run a program without it in the same terminal?

Tags: x11

Obviously I'm not looking to open another terminal and `ssh` without `-X`.  I'm actually doing this with running Matlab on another server.  So after ssh'ing into my remote server with the `-X` option, I type `matlab` and the graphics forward in as expected.

How do I run `matlab` with X11 forwarding enabled but without graphics?

Comment: so you want it to not connect to the X11 display and just use the console? try `DISPLAY= foobar` where `foobar` is your command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run `matlab` with the `-nodesktop` option.

#### Example

[image: ss #1]

***Source:*** [Launching MATLAB without the desktop](http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2010/02/22/launching-matlab-without-the-desktop/)

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to invoke `matlab` with the `-nodisplay` option

```
matlab -nodisplay
```

or simply unset the DISPLAY environment variable e.g. in bash

```
DISPLAY= matlab
```